# PHP PDO in OO format

Tags: php, pdo

I'm looking to create a CRUD class to hold all my DB queries but I'm pretty new to the OO way of thinking. for example

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=hostname;dbname=defaultDbName', 
          'username', 'password', 
          array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));

$query = 'SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE title = :title';

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':title', $myTitle);
$stmt->execute();
```

So how would I go about this. Would you put the connection information (I will be wrapping a Try Catch block around it) into the __construct so the connection is made when the class is instantiated? Then create each query into a function like so:

```
function getTitle($title){
   $query = 'SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE title = :title';
   $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
   $stmt->bindValue(':title', $title);
   $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: That would be something like `getByTitle`, and not `getTitle`. Anyways you'll end up by rewriting something like an already existing tool [e.g. Doctrine], so I would look into existing frameworks before.

Comment: This link is a really good example of doing [PHP PDO OO](https://github.com/indieteq/PHP-MySQL-PDO-Database-Class/blob/master/Db.class.php) way. Hope this helps.